# Move image around inside an overflow hidden div with buttons

Tags: html, css

I just want some guidance or links to solve this, I have a map, is an svg image and it's inside a div I've called "mainWrapper"

```
<div id="mapWrapper">
    <img src="images/map.svg" id="map"/>
</div>
```

I also included few buttons on top of everything (zoom in, zoom out, up, down, left, right) and somehow I would like to press those buttons/images, and move the inner map image around accordingly to the button. also to zoom in and out. Some guidance to achieve this?

my actual full code is:

HTML:

```css
#mapWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#zoomIn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#zoomOut {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 80px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 140px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#up {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 260px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 320px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img src="images/ZI.svg" id="zoomIn" />
<img src="images/ZO.svg" id="zoomOut" />
<img src="images/R.svg" id="right" />
<img src="images/U.svg" id="up" />
<img src="images/D.svg" id="down" />
<img src="images/L.svg" id="left" />

<div id="mapWrapper">
  <img src="images/map.svg" id="map" />
</div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: what you want to achieve is much more complicated that it may look. I would recomend you to use a library as http://leafletjs.com/ to easily implement it. I did in one of my projects and was easy enough

Comment: and even better if you follow this example with the library I posted in the first comment: http://kempe.net/blog/2014/06/14/leaflet-pan-zoom-image.html

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez thanks pal! but one quick question, since you used it already. those zoom in/zoom out buttons can be personalized? also there are buttons for move left-right-up-down? or just dragging? regards!

Comment: Refer this,http://jsfiddle.net/maunovaha/jptLfhc8/

Comment: I just followed the second example. There's no move buttoms but it's click and grab to move which imo is better. The zoom buttons can be personalized. There are just pure css. I use the example here (in case you interested): http://carretasapartments.com/mapa/mapa